# ReactiveUI command is not invoked after the command implementation throws an Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactive-programming, reactiveui

Below is a sample app that I have written to reproduce the problem. I am using `ReactiveUi 7.0.`

Command is repeatedly invoked whenever I change the text it in the `TextBox`. However, if there is an exception thrown from the command (it is captured properly by the lambda of `Search.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe`), further invocation of the command is not happening if I change the `TextBox` text.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SampleTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!--<controls:ProgressRing Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" ></controls:ProgressRing>-->
        <TextBox Margin="8 0 0 0" x:Name="SearchBox"  MinWidth="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding SearchQuery, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
using ReactiveUI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SampleTest
{
    internal class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        private SearchService service = new SearchService();
        public ReactiveCommand<string, string> Search { get; set; }

        private string searchQuery;

        public string SearchQuery
        {
            get { return this.searchQuery; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.searchQuery, value); }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Search = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async (string query) =>
            {
                var r = await this.service.SearchQuery(query, 100);
                return r;
            });

            Search.Subscribe(
                results =>
                {
                });

            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchQuery)
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .InvokeCommand(this, x => x.Search);

            Search.ThrownExceptions
            .Subscribe(ex =>
            {
                //this.ErrorInteraction.Handle($"Whilst searching, {ex.Message}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

SearchService.cs

```
  internal class SearchService
    {
        public async Task<string> SearchQuery(string searchQuery, int size = 50)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                throw new Exception("something is wrong");
                return "";
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you ever get this sorted out?  I posted almost the exact same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824104/reactiveui-7-0-how-to-handle-with-observables-that-are-disposed-when-exception-i/40833932#40833932) and ended up finding a workaround by either re-subscribing the observable inside the ThrownExceptions code, or handling the exceptions in the command code so that the ThrownExceptions never actually gets fired.  I still feel like there is a better solution tho....

Comment: No, I had to give it up and go back to 6.x